# Eclipse PyDev undefined variable using execfile

Tags: python, pydev, execfile

I am new to PyDev, so this may be a simple answer to the question that I have.

The code that I am pulling into PyDev uses a execfile instead of a import to pull in a class from another file. I don't have control over the code, so I can't change it to a import.

```
execfile("my_class.py")
my_class.function()
```

I get a undefined variable for each class that the execfile pulls in.

Is there a way to get PyDev to recognize the classes that I bring in through a execfile.  Maybe there is some kind of way that I can do a implicit import in PyDev?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Fixing that now.